# Launch another app from myapp without url scheme - jailbreak users are able to, so how?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, jailbreak

i'm trying to write a small application, a "launcher" app, that comes up when i plug my phone to power supply. Now there should be a 4x4 grid with my fav app i want to load. therefore no problem.

But how to start an app from an app? I read dozens of times that is is not possible, to do it without url shemes like tel://

How are jailbreak applications able to to this? Like Activator, PluggedIn, iSheduler... 
I have them running on my phone, and they are able to start any application, also my own, which don't have url scheme.

I tried lauchner from Erica Utilities, but it just crashed.

It is possible, but how?

Thanks for any advice
Greetings Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution: open - a commandline tool by Conrad Kramer:
http://thecydiastore.com/app/com.conradkramer.open/

Comment: I know this is old, but can you possibly tell me how it is done? I want to open an app from my own jailbreak app.

Comment: Sorry, i never used it in productiv enviroment. The App coused this question was just for myself and to download and play some music from my NAS. I managed it using iFiles url sheme.

Answer (score 1):

You can activate an app by importing these classes:

```
SBApplicationController  
SBUIController  
SBApplication
```

The SBApplicationController gets your app, the SBApplication, and then opens it using the SBUIController like so:

```
Class SBApplicationController=objc_getClass("SBApplicationController"); 

SBApplication *app=[[SBApplicationController sharedInstance] applicationWithDisplayIdentifier:@"com.company.yourapp"];//change the bundle identifier for whichever app you want

[[objc_getClass("SBUIController") sharedInstance] activateApplicationFromSwitcher:app];
```

Comment: Worked well with iOS 5.1 (Jailborken phone) - I used headers from - https://github.com/caughtinflux/iOS-6-SpringBoard-Headers.